# how to repeat the left menubar in each html page

Tags: javascript, html, menu

```
var navigation  = new Array();  // This is for the navigation.
 // ==================== Navigation ==================== //
navigation[0] = '<div id="menu">';
navigation[1] = '<ul>';
navigation[2] = '<li><a href="../about_us.htm">aboutus</a></li>';
navigation[3] = '</ul>';
navigation[4] = '</div><!-- Close TAB NAVIGATION -->';

function show(i)
{
   for (x in i)
   {
       document.write(i[x] + '\n')
   }
}
```

I have created the above function in JavaScript  for menubar now I need to call this menubar in my html file.

Comment: I am new to Java script so i would like to now how i can use this script in html page

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use `document.createElement` instead of using document write, and an array of string.

Secondly i would recommend to initialize your arrays using the `[]` literal instead of using the `Array` construct.
So something like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3]; //like this
var arr2 = new Array(1,2,3,4); // not recommended
```

The code below should work for what you want to do.

```
var navigation = document.createElement('div');
navigation.id = 'menu';
navigation.innerHTML = '<ul><li>' +
  '<li><a href="../about_us.htm">aboutus</a></li>' + '</ul></li>';
document.body.appendChild(navigation);
```

There are a few ways you can call this from your html:

1. Wrap this in a `<script></script>` tag at the bottom of the page
2. Put it in a function an set it to call onload
3. Add some other trigger in the html.

Personally i would recommend putting it in a function and adding it to onLoad event.

Javascript:

```
window.onload = appendNavigation;
function appendNavigation() {
  var navigation = document.createElement('div');
  navigation.id = 'menu';
  navigation.innerHTML = '<ul><li>' +
   '<li><a href="../about_us.htm">aboutus</a></li>' + '</ul></li>';
  document.body.appendChild(navigation);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body>
   <script src="/script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you want a working example look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d1r43w33/

Although you should be aware that when used outside of jsfiddle, you must include a script link in the html.

Comment: I am new to Java script so i would like to now how i can use this script in html page

Comment: @surabhisanduja I've added an example to the answer that you could try looking at.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.. i have called the js like this

Comment: <div id="menu">

  <script  src="../JS/aboutcara.js"> </script>
 
 </div> but its now showing anything is there any error in my js file or any error at html page

Comment: The script tag should not be nested within any tags other than the body tag, although should be the cause of your issue. But could you look in the console to check if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The variant of jonas looks good, but I would do it like this:

```js
//Autorun
    $(document).ready(function () {
        appendNavigation();
    });
    
//Function
function appendNavigation() {
  var navigation = document.createElement('div');
  navigation.id = 'menu';
  navigation.innerHTML = '<ul><li>'
                              +
                         '<a href="#">About Us</a>'//Replace # with the your url
                              +
                         '</li></ul>';
  document.body.appendChild(navigation);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just another startfunction to run/display your

Comment: You should maybe state that this requires jquery, as he might not be aware of this.